# how to replace "} by empty string ("") in Groovy

Tags: groovy, replace

In Groovy how to replace a string having `"}` by `""`

```
String s="newname1\"} newname2\"}";
So how to replace all "} by empty String.
```

i did like this `s.replaceAll("\\"}","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s="newname1\"} newname2\"}";
s.replaceAll( /"\}/, '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString="newname1\"} newname2\"}";
println yourString.replace("}", " ")
```

> result
>   newname1" newname2"

Comment: but my question is how to replace if the string is having "},please answer this if you can

Comment: @vikram i given the same answer and  look onto your string that is not not in correct format i given you the wright answer give it a try]

Comment: Sorry now I edited the question(String part) ,now can you answer, I want to eliminate both "}

Comment: what is your exact string you are changing your question again and again update your question with your real string and what are you trying and what is error so that i may help you